# java - modify method calling RPC object for SOAP Ws

Tags: java, soap, rpc

I need to override a method in a class stub using in my ws client. The problem is that this class (and other) are auto generated (by Eclipse with the wsdl file).

So, I don't want to override the method directly in the class stub

Is possible to do a "wrapper" or "inject" a method in this class based on this method
Or is possible to "handle" the call object and to modify it before invocation ?

```
public com.www.data.GetTripRecordResponseTypeTripRecordReport[] getTripRecord(com.www.data.GetTripRecordRequestType getTripRecordRequest/*,String address*/) throws java.rmi.RemoteException {
        if (super.cachedEndpoint == null) {
            throw new org.apache.axis.NoEndPointException();
        }
        org.apache.axis.client.Call _call = createCall();
        _call.setOperation(_operations[1]);
        _call.setUseSOAPAction(true);
        _call.setSOAPActionURI("getTripRecord");
        _call.setEncodingStyle(null);
            _call.setSOAPVersion(org.apache.axis.soap.SOAPConstants.SOAP11_CONSTANTS);
        _call.setOperationName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://localhost/data", "getTripRecord"));

// Code to inject before invocating the _call object
        if(address != null)
                {
                    Transport trans = _call.getTransportForProtocol("http");
                    trans.setUrl(address);
                    _call.setTransport(trans);
                }

                try {        java.lang.Object _resp = _call.invoke(new java.lang.Object[] {getTripRecordRequest});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the class and override the method there. Even better try and get a result back from the existing method and then try to work on it in your code.

Comment: Yes, I thought about it but I cannot manipulate the result of this method. I need to intercept the method just before _call.invoke() in the middle part of the method. For it, i think to use Spring AOP and "intercept" the object _call before invokation. Do you think it is possible ?

Comment: I cannot really see the _call.invoke() line, but regardless you can just override it in a subclass and copy the code you need, anything else should work as you want it. Regarding Spring AOP I cannot really commend on that.